# Why does it get timed out when using nginx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx

I'm running rails on nginx. Then I have the function to deliver emails to all regiestered users at once.
I did ran this but it got timed out error. How can I fix this? How can I modify my configuration?

**controller** (There  are over 10000 users so it means this mailer procedure repeats for 10000 times)

```
users.each do |user|
    if user.nomail.blank?
        CallMailer.call_email_to(user.email, subject, body).deliver
        sent_to_count = sent_to_count + 1
    end
end
```

Then it gets this timed out error.

`The connection has timed out`
`The server www.foofooexample.com is taking too long to respond.`

Here's my nginx's conf

**etc/nginx/conf.d/foo.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name foofooexample.com;
    root /var/www/html/foo/public;
    client_max_body_size 5M;

    keepalive_timeout  1200;
    proxy_connect_timeout 1200;
    proxy_read_timeout    1200;
    proxy_send_timeout    1200;
.
.
.
```

Comment: Such a task shouldn't be done within a (waiting) web request. You should do it in the background, there are many gems to do that such like [sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/).

Comment: @Tamer Thanks for a comment! does sidekiq do what exactly I'm doing in controller? It's loading all the users and send message to all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one of the comments mentioned, you want to offload this to a background worker using something such as [`sidekiq`](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Delayed-Extensions), which comes with an `ActionMailer` extension for sending email in the background.

After installing, instead of

```
CallMailer.call_email_to(user.email, subject, body).deliver
```

You would use:

```
CallMailer.delay.call_email_to(user.email, subject, body)
```

Also, I'd advise you use [`find_each`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_each) instead of `each`. This is because `each` will load all of your `User` objects into memory, whereas `find_each` will load them in batches. See the linked documentation for example usage.